# CORE, quagga, zebra daemon - issue with autostart router OS

Tags: networking, services, emulation

I need to start few simulation in CORE. On ubuntu 16.04 I haven't any problems to correct configuration. I do steps from many tutorials in network and everything works fine. But on 17.10 i have strange trouble. After star simulation the zebra daemon don't' start automatically on all routers and I need to this manually on each "devices". I fight with this more than 5 days and I'm start be frustrated.

I see that now quagga install different as tutorial shows, but I don't know how fix it.
Example:
After

```
aptitude install quagga
```

I see that file `quagga` on `/etc/init.d/` don't creating. The same like `/etc/quagga/daemons`

Really don't know what I should input to post to help you to help me...

For example I do steps from this tutorial: http://www.brianlinkletter.com/how-to-build-a-network-of-linux-routers-using-quagga/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after few long days I find resolution.

Firstly I was fixed links from defaulted installed in `zebra.service` witch we can find on `/lib/systemd/system/`. Run `zebra.service` on some text editor and change lines 4, 10, 11, 13. Write directory:

`/usr/lib/quagga/zebra.conf` instead `/etc/quagga/zebra.conf`

The ultimately file should looks:

```
 1 [Unit]
 2 Description=GNU Zebra routing manager
 3 After=network.target
 4 ConditionPathExists=/usr/lib/quagga/zebra.conf
 5 Documentation=man:zebra
 6
 7 [Service]
 8 Type=forking
 9 ExecStartPre=/sbin/ip route flush proto zebra
10 ExecStartPre=-/bin/chmod -f 640 /etc/quagga/vtysh.conf /usr/lib/quagga/zebra.conf
11 ExecStartPre=-/bin/chown -f quagga:quagga /run/quagga /usr/lib/quagga/zebra.conf
12 ExecStartPre=-/bin/chown -f quagga:quaggavty /etc/quagga/vtysh.conf
13 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/zebra -d -A 127.0.0.1 -f /usr/lib/quagga/zebra.conf
14 Restart=on-abort
15 RuntimeDirectory=quagga
16
17 [Install]
18 WantedBy=network.target
```

Save file and restart system daemons using `systemctl daemon-reload`. Start zebra service using `system zebra start`.

Another way for it is create of symlink looking on `zebra.conf`. To do this use:

`ln -s /usr/lib/quagga/zebra.conf /etc/quagga/zebra.conf`

Now you was fixed wrong implemented package repository from Ubuntu 16.04 to now.

On the second step we need to fix a CORE installation. Exactly few stuff what doesn't configured by default.
I noticed problem with group access. CORE don't want to start zebra.service automatically, because root user haven't access to specific temporary folder. As I saw root user wasn't a member of 'quaggavty' group.

To change this situation just add root to group:
`usermod -a -G  quaggavt root`

Restart CORE and enjoy property working program.